# Assignment problem with time constraints on both axes

Tags: algorithms

I have a number of agents and tasks.  In my case, the agents and the tasks have time constraints: so agent1 loves doing task1, but task1 must be done at 10am or 11am, and agent1 is only available after 1130am, also, task1 and task2 can happen at the same time, but the cost increases if so.

Is there a way to introduce duplicate rows/cols or some such to account for this while still applying a naive assignment problem algorithm (e.g. Hungarian)?

Answer (score 1):

If all tasks take one hour and are required to start "on the hour", then you can make a bunch of copies of each agent and each task, one per hour of the day.

For more complicated situations, I don't know of any way to represent this as an assignment problem.  You might do better to solve it using integer linear programming, which is much more flexible (though potentially can be much harder to solve).